# Hedging Strategy for American Option

Tags: finance, economics, actuarial-science

Good day,

> I was asked to devise a hedging strategy for an American Option given the following claims.
>
> **Note, $r=0$ and the underlying stock pays a dividend of $1$ at time $t=1.5$**

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& S(t=0,\omega) & S(t=1,\omega)^* & S(t=2,\omega)^* \\ \hline
\omega_1 & 6& 9& 11\\ \hline
\omega_2 & 6& 9& 7\\ \hline
\omega_3 & 6& 4& 7\\ \hline
\omega_4 & 6& 4& 1\\ \hline
\end{array}

I found this question which seems identical except this person did not use dynamic programming to find the value of the option at each node.

I found the same risk neutral probabilities but I found the values at the nodes to be as follows

$$V_{amer}(0)=\dfrac{8}{5}, V_{amer}(1,\{ \omega_1,\omega_2\})=3, V_{amer}(1,\{ \omega_3,\omega_4\})=\dfrac{2}{3}$$
$$V_{amer}(1,\{ \omega_1\})=6, V_{amer}(1,\{ \omega_2\})=2, V_{amer}(1,\{ \omega_3\})=2, V_{amer}(1,\{ \omega_4\})=0$$

The comment on this (https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/31892/constructing-a-hedging-strategy-for-an-american-option) post says its how much stock we need to short against the option at each node but Im not quite sure how that makes a hedging strategy.

Comment: I think the question asks you to figure out how much of the underlying you should hold at each time step. You can do that by working backwards and analyzing what happens for the one-period binomial tree.